# The RemoveDir task failed unexPectedly

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Anyone else getting this error when building from VS?

Error       The "RemoveDir" task failed unexpectedly.
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MessagingException: Unable to connect to the Server in order to execute the SSH command
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommandRunner.d__8.MoveNext() in E:\A_work\7\s\External\messaging\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh\SshCommandRunner.cs:line 118
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommandRunner.d__5.MoveNext() in E:\A_work\7\s\External\messaging\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh\SshCommandRunner.cs:line 81
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommands.d__10.MoveNext() in E:\A_work\7\s\External\messaging\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh\SshCommands.cs:line 105
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommands.d__14.MoveNext() in E:\A_work\7\s\External\messaging\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh\SshCommands.cs:line 152
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.ISshServiceExtensions.d__6.MoveNext() in E:\A_work\7\s\External\messaging\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh\Extensions\ISshServiceExtensions.cs:line 105
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.RemoveDir.Execute() in E:\A_work\7\s\src\MSBuild\Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks\MsBuildTasks\RemoveDir.cs:line 20
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MessagingException: Unable to connect to the Server in order to execute the SSH command
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommandRunner.d__8.MoveNext() in E:\A_work\7\s\External\messaging\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh\SshCommandRunner.cs:line 118
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommandRunner.d__5.MoveNext() in E:\A_work\7\s\External\messaging\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh\SshCommandRunner.cs:line 81
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommands.d__10.MoveNext() in E:\A_work\7\s\External\messaging\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh\SshCommands.cs:line 105
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommands.d__14.MoveNext() in E:\A_work\7\s\External\messaging\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh\SshCommands.cs:line 152
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.ISshServiceExtensions.d__6.MoveNext() in E:\A_work\7\s\External\messaging\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh\Extensions\ISshServiceExtensions.cs:line 105<--- Paga.iOS

Comment: This is happening in Xamarin.ios if i am not wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the many weird Xamarin things.  Try cleaning the solution and restarting VS